# Block the verify e-mail address e-mail from being sent in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laravel Notifiable trait on my user model so users have to verify their e-mail address before being able to login, this works fine.

However, I want to delay the sending of this e-mail until a later point in the application (when the admin manually confirms each user).

How do I prevent Laravel from sending the verify e-mail on account creation?

When creating a user manually you can use the SendsPasswordResetEmails trait to send the verification email whenever you like in your application:

```
use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
$this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
```

The problem is I can't find this code in the standard Laravel authentication scaffolding to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Notifiable` trait is not what is sending the email verification to the user, but the `MustVerifyEmail` interface that your `User` model implements.

So in order to do it manually what you need to do is remove this lines from the

`EventServiceProvider` `$listen` mappings:

```
Registered::class => [
    SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
]
```

and then at later point you can find the `User` to which you want to send the email verification and send the email like this:

```
User::find($userId)->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

Answer (score 1):

As @nakov mentioned, it is the `MustVerifyEmail` interface that Laravel uses to perform its magic. Laravel checks if the class to be notified (i.e. `User`) implements the `MustVerifyEmail` interface, and if so, sends out the verification notification.

While you could remove the `Registered` event listener from your `EventServiceProvider`, you can also just remove `implements MustVerifyEmail` from your `User` class.

By keeping the event listener in tact and simply removing the `MustVerifyEmail` interface from your `User` class, you keep the automated email verification system in tact in case you do want to create another type of `User` class does get automated email verification notifications.

So, remove `implements MustVerifyEmail` from your `User` class, and then manually call `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` on your user whenever you want to send out the verification email.